Why are these transformer windings used connecting the switch and the series pass regulator in this circuit?
I am looking into this multi-output forward converter and cannot figure why these highlighted windings are connected to the switching side. There's already an inductor to handle the recovery reset. Can anyone tell me what these windings do? 
